# Why is WebView2 in dark mode?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, webview2

I am using a WebView2 control in VB .NET. When I determine the source, the file is shown in dark mode. How can I change that? The property "DefaultBackgroundColor" is set to "White".

The source:

```
<html>
<body>
<b>Test</b>
</body>
</html>
```

The output:
[image]

I am expecting the html-code to be not shown with black background.

Comment: Can you provide some code? There are some doubts about your webview as the code labeled as "The source" should be parsed as HTML not as a String as your image shows

Comment: Usually Windows Forms set the “black” color where there is a Transparent Color. Take a look in your code if there is some Control with Transparent background color.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj I am not in front of the PC right now but I just set the property "source" to an URI which points to local file not ending on .html. Is that why the content is shown as a text? Will check later about the transparent color.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.